# Giving to wordpress it's own directory cause login loop

Tags: htaccess

I have done a fresh wordpress installation from a subdirectory. I've followed the official wordpress guide to give wordpress it's own directory, but now I have a login loop problem, I'm not able to login to the dashboard and every attempts will redirect me to the login sreen. How I can fix this?

I have this code inside my `.htaccess` root file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /web/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ web/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

And this is the `.htaccess` file inside the directory where wordpress is installed

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

> ...this is the `.htaccess` file inside the directory where wordpress is installed

That is certainly incorrect as it's sending requests back to the root. You can remove the `RewriteBase` directive and remove the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string, ie `/index.php` should be `index.php`.

For example:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I've "commented out" the `RewriteBase` directive, rather than removing it completely.

By removing the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *substitution* then it is seen as relative to the current directory. ie. Relative to `/web`, so this rewrites the request to `/web/index.php`, not `/index.php`. (The `RewriteBase` directive would override this.)

Comment: Ok, I missed this part but it's not written inside the wordpress guide. I was editing the file to force the use of https on the whole site. I was thinking that the error was there. I will test and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I've tested, but it will continue to give me the login loop issue :( ! I think that this is because of this line to force https `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`?

Comment: Although that doesn't really have anything to do with the subdirectory / login? That will result a redirect loop if you are using a front-end proxy to manage your SSL eg. Cloudflare Flexible SSL. (?)

Comment: What exactly is the redirect loop you are seeing? From / to URLs? I would certainly make sure your browser cache is cleared, since any erroneous 301 redirects are cached persistently by the browser. Do you have files outside of the `/web` subdirectory that need to be accessible? If not, then your root `.htaccess` file can be greatly simplified. As it is, the root `.htaccess` file is not strictly correct (although unlikely to be the cause of this current issue).

Comment: for redirect loop I mean that after inserting the credentials I will not redirected to the dashboard but I will see again the login page. In the root there is only the folde where wordpress files are stored, nothing else.